# Get iPhone rotation and orientation to rotate 3d object in real time

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion

I'd like to develop an app in which I should get iPhone rotation and orientation. Once I get this values, I'd like to make a cube which follows the device rotation/orientation.

Do you know any web site which talks about it? Or do you know where should I search for infos about it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CMMotionManager to start getting motion updates. Poll the motion manager using a timer; on each poll, retrieve the motion manager's `deviceMotion.attitude`. You can then do whatever you want in response to the device's change in attitude. I believe the most accurate way, if you're going to be moving your image in 3D, is to use OpenGL with the attitude's `quaternion`. But if you're just making, say, a level, you can use the `rotationMatrix` instead (and apply a transform based on it).

Comment: This will give you a general sense, but it is not a true 3D example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p789attitudeRotation/ch25p1046attitudeRotation/ViewController.m

Comment: So if I use attitude it will give me every data (both accelerometer and gyroscope)?

Comment: Anyway I think you gave me a good starting point, I will try to develop from your example!!:)